# d3 translateExtent when zoomed

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3 v4 to draw a collapsible tree - see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MaryBartlett/xcgv6oe6/6/)

I'm setting the translateable world using `translateExtent` but when you zoom in or out, the translateable world doesn't adjust. You can see in my example (lines 479-514) I've attempted to fix this by multiplying by the scale or dividing by scale where appropriate but that hasn't worked. (The ideal is that when you move at any point there is always one 'card' visible - it works at 1x zoom).

Another complication is that the top node of the tree needs to be centralised in the browser, so everything is offset relative to that.

I've seen a few other mentions that `translateExtent` doesn't work with zooming in or out but wondered if anyone had managed to get it to work?

Comment: `zoom.translateExtent([[right, down], [left, up]]);` must be  `zoom.translateExtent([[left, up], [right, down]]);`, have you fixed it ?